# Show a dynamic text depending on the day

Tags: 7, views

I'd like my Drupal website to show at the right top something like:

> ____ day (eg. **Medicine** day)

and fill `__________` dynamically depending on the current day.

I will create a new content type `DayType` or something like that, with two fields:

- `Title`
- `Date`

My question is:

How can I show in `__________` the title depending on the current day?

I could do that with a *View*, but what I don't know is how to show it on the right-top, and not apparently in a block or just in a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use views_embed_view() to get the output of a view manually. Supposing your view is called 'days' and you want to display the output of this view:

```
print t('Today is @dayname day.', array('@dayname', views_embed_view('days')));
```

(This assumes the output of your view is just some text, and contains no HTML.)

By 'on the right-top', do you mean the page title? In any case, you could set a variable in your theme's preprocess function (which goes in the theme's template.php), like this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['daystring'] = t('Today is @dayname day.', array('@dayname', views_embed_view('days')));
}
```

Now, in your page.tpl.php, you can write something like this:

```
print $daystring;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't mean in the title, but maybe in the header, or at the top of the right sidebar.

Comment: Let me ask you something: I have to modify the theme, right? I mean, if I'm using Garland, I will have to overwrite Garland files? I'm just thinking about what would happen if it gets updated or something. Just to ask. Your solution seems pretty easy. All I have to do is to see where should I locate the text :)

Comment: My method talks about modifying the theme, yes. Of course, you must not modify garland, but nothing says you can't make a copy of it, rename it, and make your changes in the copy!

Comment: Later on, caching of the day could become an issue.